# How to count all integers less than a given integer and having two contigous digits as y?

Tags: string, algorithm, number-theory

Suppose i have been given a number 54432 .How to count all numbers less than 54432 and having last two digits as 1 ? i.e all the numbers of form xxx11 and xxx11 < 54432 .Here x can be any digits but xxx11 < 54432 should hold.

What is count of all the numbers of form x11xx and x11xx < 54432 ?

How to solve this in general and fast way i.e any number other than 1 , say y and arbitrary position of two contiguous digits as y and count of all such numbers less than a given integer.

can we solve this problem using strings ?

Like for 54411 , total count is 545 . Just remove 11 part and add 1.
for 54112 ,total count is 543 , just remove 11 part .

Comment: Please add the fact that numbers like `411` or `511` are also eligible in the count of `54411`.

Comment: @vivek_23 How ?

Comment: Then how is `545` the answer for `54411`? See [this](https://ideone.com/o5ylz1) and [this](http://ideone.com/aCYQuU).

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes i am wrong . can you provide procedure to find the answer ?

Comment: @MrSmith42 I tried to solve it by multiplication .for example in case of 54411 , we will have 5*10*10 + 45  = 545 .But this procedure becomes too lengthy !

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number X digits long and want the count the number of numbers with Y digits fixed (e.g. ending in 11 or 65, or having 85 in positions 2 and 3), then the answer is 10 ^ (X - Y). Fr example, you start with a three digit number and want to count the numbers with a 1 in the middle. There are only two digits that can vary: varying these two digits make the numbers 00 to 99 i.e. 100 numbers.

So the count of 5 digit numbers with two 1 digits at the end gives the answer 10 ^ 3 = 1000.

Now, if you want to restrict the possible numbers to those less than a starting number. You're limiting the largest number that the varying digits can take to something less than - in you example - 999. You've got the right in your last para, but consider edge cases (11 at the start etc etc).

Comment: I was trying to show you how to think about it, not how to do it. Some self-help is required :)

Comment: @MrSmith42 I tried to solve it by multiplication .for example in case of 54411 , we will have 5*10*10 + 45  = 545 .But this procedure becomes too lengthy .I tried to find some shorted way but i failed